# Issue with word 'incentives'

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, differences

I am proofreading some documentation, and this sentence bothers me:

> This incentives users to install the app.

Is the use of 'incentives' here grammatically incorrect?

Are these two alternatives better?

1. *This incentivizes users to install the app.*
2. *This encourages users to install the app.*

Answer (score 3):

No, it is wrong; *incentives* is a noun. What you *should* put, is the verb "incentivizes". And yes, both your alternatives are perfectly fine and better.

Comment: Before correcting it, make sure that "incentive" verb is not a specialized jargon of the field.

Comment: @GEdgar - I guess it would be good to be aware, but even if it were popular in one field, that doesn't mean a proofreader shouldn't help the author write in standard English, especially here, where I can't imagine anyone objecting to "incentivize."